# Symfony2 - Twig updates are not rendering

Tags: php, symfony, caching, twig, symfony-2.6

I am a beginner in Symfony2. I have created my first template and I can access to it through the URL **http://localhost/mylibrary-web/web/app_dev.php/hello/Test**.

Here the content of my `src/MyLibrary/LibraryBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig` file :

```
Hello {{ name }}!
```

I do not have the *toolbar* (because I do not have the `</body>` element, but if I update the `index.html.twig` file with :

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hi {{ name }}!
  </body>
</html>
```

nothing changes. These modifications are not considered. The old content is still display when I call the URL **http://localhost/mylibrary-web/web/app_dev.php/hello/Test**.

I tried to clear the cache with the command line `php app\console cache:clear`. I also tried to hard delete the cache by deleting the `app\cache` directory. Finally, I tried to add the following line to the `config_dev.yml` file :

```
twig:
    cache: false
```

Unfortunately, nothing changes, I still have the old content displayed.

Am I missing something to update the twig file ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Edit :

Here the code of the `src/MyLibrary\LibraryBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php` file :

```
<?php

namespace MyLibrary\LibraryBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('MyLibraryLibraryBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }
}
```

and the result of the command line `php app\console route:debug` :

```
[router] Current routes
 Name                        Method Scheme Host Path
 _wdt                        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_wdt/{token}
 _profiler_home              ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/
 _profiler_search            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search
 _profiler_search_bar        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search_bar
 _profiler_purge             ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/purge
 _profiler_info              ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/info/{about}
 _profiler_phpinfo           ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/phpinfo
 _profiler_search_results    ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/search/results
 _profiler                   ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}
 _profiler_router            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/router
 _profiler_exception         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception
 _profiler_exception_css     ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
 _configurator_home          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/
 _configurator_step          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/step/{index}
 _configurator_final         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/final
 _twig_error_test            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_error/{code}.{_format}
 my_library_library_homepage ANY    ANY    ANY  /hello/{name}
 homepage                    ANY    ANY    ANY  /app/example
```

Edit 2 :

Here the definition of the **my_library_library_homepage** route :

```
my_library_library_homepage:
    path:     /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: MyLibraryLibraryBundle:Default:index }
```

and here the result when I grep `Hello {{ name }}!` :

- C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Resources\skeleton\acme-demo-bundle\Acme\DemoBundle\Resources\views\Demo\hello.html.twig
- C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Resources\skeleton\acme-demo-bundle\Acme\DemoBundle\Resources\views\Secured\hello.html.twig
- C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\vendor\sensio\generator-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Tests\Generator\BundleGeneratorTest.php
- C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\vendor\twig\extensions\doc\i18n.rst
- C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\vendor\twig\twig\doc\api.rst
- C:\wamp\www\mylibrary-web\vendor\twig\twig\doc\intro.rst

Comment: I think you edit wrong template. Show route for /hello pattern and action that render the template. Also try to delete browser cache.

Comment: Can you please show us the controller code ?

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru : Thx for your help. I have updated my post with the result of the command line `php app\console route:debug`

Comment: @kba : Thx for your help ! i have updated my post with the code of the `DefaultController.php` file.

Comment: Ok. Show please `my_library_library_homepage` route definition and try to grep your source files for `Hello {{ name }}!` pattern. You will see if there is more possible templates or not.

Comment: @kba : I have updated my post with the definition of the route `my_library_library_homepage` and the result of the grep command.

Comment: @kba : Just to try, I have restarted the wamp services and the page has been updated...

Comment: did you find any solution @rolandl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be very strange but... after restarting the services of wamp, everything seems to work correctly...

Answer (score 2):

First, check if you have permission to write in the folder cache:

```
app/cache/dev/
```

Delete all files there and run:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
php app/console cache:warmup --env=dev
```

Comment: Thx for your help ! I checked the permission and run the 2 command line without success.

Comment: Did you already checked you "routing.yml" file ? Maybe you are redirecting for the "old" sources. Check also inside your controller action if you are passing correctly the "link" to you twig template.

Comment: I have updated my post with the routes and the code of the `DefaultController.php` file.

Comment: So to see changes made during development, I have to clear the cache?